# create a table within a CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'd like to have a table that I can play around with, but that can be reference by the overall CTE

---

```
    CTE_MONTHS as (
   DECLARE @MONTHS TABLE ([NUMBER] int, NAME varchar(max))
   INSERT INTO @MONTHS
   select ([NUMBER],[NAME]) VALUES
   ('1' ,'JANUARY')
   ,('2' ,'FEBRUARY')
   ,('3' ,'MARCH')
   ,('4' ,'APRIL')
   ,('5' ,'MAY')
   ,('6' ,'JUNE')
   ,('7' ,'JULY')
   ,('8' ,'AUGUST')
   ,('9' ,'SEPTEMBER')
   ,('10','OCTOBER')
   ,('11','NOVEMBER')
   ,('12','DECEMBER')
   select * from @MONTHS
   )
```

---

Comment: Does it have to be a CTE or would a temp table work?

Comment: i'd like it to be part of a larger CTE..and this way i don't have to keep changing a table

Comment: You can't have procedural code inside a CTE - it can only contain a `SELECT` statement. You need to declare and insert to the table variable before it. Or just select the values directly as part of CTE_MONTHS

Comment: Read this: https://www.sqlshack.com/inserts-and-updates-with-ctes-in-sql-server-common-table-expressions/

Comment: I don't want to insert or update any tables.  I basically want to be able to just list a bunch of values in a cte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you've got things in all the wrong order. Try this instead:

```
   DECLARE @MONTHS TABLE ([NUMBER] int, NAME varchar(max));

   WITH CTE_MONTHS AS 
   (
        SELECT [NUMBER], [NAME] 
        FROM (VALUES ('1' ,'JANUARY')
                    ,('2' ,'FEBRUARY')
                    ,('3' ,'MARCH')
                    ,('4' ,'APRIL')
                    ,('5' ,'MAY')
                    ,('6' ,'JUNE')
                    ,('7' ,'JULY')
                    ,('8' ,'AUGUST')
                    ,('9' ,'SEPTEMBER')
                    ,('10','OCTOBER')
                    ,('11','NOVEMBER')
                    ,('12','DECEMBER')) AS m([NUMBER], [NAME])
   )
   INSERT INTO @MONTHS ([NUMBER], [NAME])
   SELECT [NUMBER],[NAME] FROM CTE_MONTHS;

   SELECT * FROM @MONTHS;
```

In this case though, the CTE is achieving nothing. You might as well just write this:

```
   DECLARE @MONTHS TABLE ([NUMBER] int, NAME varchar(max));

   INSERT INTO @MONTHS ([NUMBER], [NAME])
   SELECT [NUMBER], [NAME] 
   FROM (VALUES ('1' ,'JANUARY')
               ,('2' ,'FEBRUARY')
               ,('3' ,'MARCH')
               ,('4' ,'APRIL')
               ,('5' ,'MAY')
               ,('6' ,'JUNE')
               ,('7' ,'JULY')
               ,('8' ,'AUGUST')
               ,('9' ,'SEPTEMBER')
               ,('10','OCTOBER')
               ,('11','NOVEMBER')
               ,('12','DECEMBER')) AS m([NUMBER], [NAME]);

   SELECT * FROM @MONTHS;
```

Comment: i think i confused everyone with the @, but i left a response below

Answer (score 1):

In that case, I don't really see the problem. You just use code like this:

```
WITH CTE_DATA 
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(Effective_Date) as MONTH_NUM,
                    DATENAME(MONTH, Effective_date) as MONTH_NAME,
                    ACTIVE_DATE,
                    INACTIVE_DATE,
                    TN,
                    MARKET_NPAS
   FROM SEP19TN2
   WHERE [LRN] <> 'Y _OOL' 
   AND MONTH(Effective_Date) IS NOT NULL
),
CTE_MONTHS AS 
(
     SELECT [NUMBER], [NAME] 
     FROM (VALUES ('1' ,'JANUARY')
                 ,('2' ,'FEBRUARY')
                 ,('3' ,'MARCH')
                 ,('4' ,'APRIL')
                 ,('5' ,'MAY')
                 ,('6' ,'JUNE')
                 ,('7' ,'JULY')
                 ,('8' ,'AUGUST')
                 ,('9' ,'SEPTEMBER')
                 ,('10','OCTOBER')
                 ,('11','NOVEMBER')
                 ,('12','DECEMBER')) AS m([NUMBER], [NAME])
)
-- and main query goes here - it can reference both CTEs
```

As a side note, try to name things for what they hold, not how they're implemented. Adding CTE_ on the front of the expression really adds no value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I was clear before, but I'm not trying to make a temp table.  I'd like to avoid any inserts or any table creations (even if it's a temp.)

I have something like the below...and I'd like to be able to change the VALUES in the script for CTE_MONTHS before I hit F5.  So, for example, maybe I'd like 9 to be February and then run the query.

---

```
WITH CTE_DATA as
 (select distinct
 MONTH(Effective_Date) as MONTH_NUM,
 DATENAME(MONTH, Effective_date) as MONTH_NAME,
 ACTIVE_DATE,
 INACTIVE_DATE,
 TN,
 MARKET_NPAS
 FROM SEP19TN2
 WHERE [LRN] <> 'Y _OOL' and MONTH(Effective_Date) is not null),

CTE_MONTHS as (
 --DECLARE MONTHS TABLE ([NUMBER] int, NAME varchar(max))
 --INSERT INTO MONTHS
 select ([NUMBER],[NAME]) VALUES
 ('1' ,'JANUARY'  )
 ,('2' ,'FEBRUARY' )
 ,('3' ,'MARCH'   )
 ,('4' ,'APRIL'   )
 ,('5' ,'MAY'     )
 ,('6' ,'JUNE'    )
 ,('7' ,'JULY'    )
 ,('8' ,'AUGUST')
 ,('9' ,'SEPTEMBER')
 ,('10','OCTOBER')
 ,('11','NOVEMBER')
 ,('12','DECEMBER')
 --select * from @MONTHS
 ) 

and here goes some kind of query that references both CTEs


 ***
```